# How to get name of category based on id?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to assign correctly names of some categories and topics. How can I get names based on id ?

I have `career_solutions` table with column `topic_category_id` (which is the category id of career solution) . I need to get the name of category from  column `id` / `category` from table `categories`.

Now, I only get the id of category from `career_solutions` with `{{ $user->topic_category_id }}`

**Here is my controller:**

```
 $user = CareerSolution::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->join('role_users' , 'role_users.user_id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('roles' , 'roles.id', '=', 'role_users.role_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.id', '=', 'events.subject')
        ->orWhere('career_solutions.topic_category_id' ,'=', $category->id)
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', '=', 'users.username')
        ->select('career_solutions.id as id','subject','users.id as user_id','username', 'profile_picture', 'role_id', 'optional', 'topic_category_id')
         ->get ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join category table too and get categoryname from that table

```
$user = CareerSolution::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->join('role_users' , 'role_users.user_id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('roles' , 'roles.id', '=', 'role_users.role_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'career_solutions.topic_category_id')
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.id', '=', 'events.subject')
        ->orWhere('career_solutions.topic_category_id' ,'=', $category->id)
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', '=', 'users.username')
        ->select('career_solutions.id as id','subject','users.id as user_id','username', 'profile_picture', 'role_id', 'optional', 'topic_category_id','categories.name')
         ->get ();
```

and call `{{ $user->name }}`